# Scan sql field of type DATE into go struct field

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I have a google bigquery that has a DATE type field, not a DATETIME.

How can I represent this field in go in the most natural way?

I have tried:

```
type Record {
    Date  string `bigquery:"the_date"`
}
```

I get an error while doing `iterator.Next(&record)` of `schema field the_date of type DATE is not assignable to struct field Date of type string`

I have also tried with Date being of type `time.Time` as well as `sql.NullTime` and both show the same error for those types as well.

I can't seem to find anything online referring to getting simple date values into a basic struct member without some sort of string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `civil.Date`

```
type Record {
    Date  civil.Date `bigquery:"the_date"`
}
```

[From the Go BigQuery docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#section-readme)

> Each BigQuery column type corresponds to one or more Go types; a
> matching struct field must be of the correct type. The correspondences
> are:

```
STRING      string
BOOL        bool
INTEGER     int, int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32
FLOAT       float32, float64
BYTES       []byte
TIMESTAMP   time.Time
DATE        civil.Date
TIME        civil.Time
DATETIME    civil.DateTime
NUMERIC     *big.Rat
BIGNUMERIC  *big.Rat
```